Transformation of probability densities
I am having some trouble understanding this claim from Chapter-2 of Bishop's Deep Learning book.
Any density $p(y)$ can be obtained from a fixed density $q(x)$ that is everywhere non-zero by making a nonlinear change of variable $y = f(x)$ in which $f(x)$ is a monotonic function such that $0\le f'(x)< \infty$.
Why should $q(x)$ have to be non-zero everywhere?

It's hard to say why the non-zero assumption on $q$ is done without seeing the proof, but it seems to me to be a typo, and it is $p$ that needs to be non-zero everywhere.
Indeed, suppose we are working on the interval $[0, 1]$ and consider
$$
q(x) = 1
\qquad
p(y) = 
\begin{cases}
3/2 &\text{if } 0 \leq y \leq 1/3 \text{ or } 2/3\leq y\leq 1, \\
0 &\text{if } 1/3 < y < 2/3.
\end{cases}
$$
Then the support of $q$ is connected, but the support of $p$ is not, so any function $f$ transforming $q$ to $p$ must be discontinuous.
On the other hand, if we assume that $p$ is non-zero everywhere then we can explicitly construct $f$ by taking
$$
Q(x)
= \int_{-\infty}^x q(t) \;\mathrm{d}t,
\qquad
P(x)
= \int_{-\infty}^y p(t) \;\mathrm{d}t,
\qquad
f
= P^{-1} \circ Q,
$$
where $p > 0$ ensures that $P$ is invertible and so that the corresponding $f$ is differentiable.

My understanding of the proof also involved constructing f=$P^{-1} \circ Q $ but my guess is that P can still be inverted as long as p is zero only at isolated points. Is that not true? The "everywhere zero" requirement seemed a bit too strong.

Yeah, the "everywhere zero" can most likely be loosened somewhat. Indeed, probability densities are only defined up to modifications on a measure-zero set, so we can easily loosen the requirement to "almost everywhere zero." I wouldn't be surprised if it could be weakened a bit further
